# Displaying multiple images from a numpy array in a single plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array of shape (7,4,100,100) which means 7 images of size 100x100 with depth 4. I want to display all of them on a single plot. I tried following using matplotlib:

```
    input_arr=numpy.load(r'C:\Users\x\samples.npy')

    for i, el in enumerate(input_arr):
        #moving axis to use plt: i.e [4,100,100] to [100,100,4]
        array2= numpy.moveaxis(input_arr[i],0,-1)
        plt.subplot(3,3, i + 1), plt.imshow(array2[i])
    plt.show()
```

But it squeezes the images in the plot as shown in the figure below where image at left is a single image and other one is the plot of multiple images. any solution or any other approach?
[image]

Comment: Please fix the indentation issues in your code.

Comment: Please also provide short example of `input_arr`

Comment: Question seeking debugging help ("why isn't the code working?") need to provide a [mcve]. In this case is really easy, just use some random data.

Comment: What do you mean by squeeze? If it means what I think it means, you could try something like `plt.subplot(3, 3, i+1)` instead.

Comment: @Jaime Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you moved the axis with `np.moveaxis`, you already indexed the input array to get only the *i-th* component of the array. So when you then use `imshow`, you don't need to plot the *i-th* index of `array2`, but the whole of `array2`.

```
for i, el in enumerate(input_arr):
    #moving axis to use plt: i.e [4,100,100] to [100,100,4]
    array2 = numpy.moveaxis(input_arr[i], 0, -1)
    plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(array2)      # <- I changed this line
plt.show()
```

You can confirm this by printing the shape of `array2` and `array2[i]`

```
print array2.shape
# (100, 100, 4) 
print array2[i].shape
# (100, 4)
```